# Workflow error method PUT The remote server returned 400 bad request

Tags: sharepoint-server, designer-workflow, workflow-manager

I'm a new in Sharepoint.

I have 2 server and both of them joined to the same domain name `ABC`

The first server: `192.168.1.110` is a database server and domain name is `SQLServer`. I installed MSSQLServer on it.

The second server: `192.168.1.111`, I installed Sharepoint Server 2013 and domain is `SPServer`

When I configured workflow service successfully: 
`Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "http://spserver/sites/abc" -WorkflowHostUri "http://192.168.1.111:12291" -AllowOAuthHttp`

Then I tried to create a simple workflow and put it to start automatically when an item is created

But the problem is the worflow doesn't start any way. I log to `spserver` and open event viewer. I found the following error:

EventData

method PUT 
  uri `http://192.168.1.111:12291/$Workflows/5eb9b2ea-d936-4764-b6cf-564c59004218`
  errorMessage System.ArgumentException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. The api-version in the query string is not supported. Either remove it from the Uri or use one of '2012-03'..TrackingId:f1cfdc01-b5dd-4fa5-b7c9-323de9e97f33_GDomain,TimeStamp:8/14/2014 5:05:11 AM ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.ServiceBusResourceOperations.GetAsyncResult`1.EndGetResponse(GetAsyncResult`1 thisPtr, IAsyncResult ar) at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- Server stack trace: Exception rethrown at [0]: at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result) at Microsoft.Workflow.Gateway.HttpAsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result) at Microsoft.Workflow.Gateway.WorkflowServiceGateway.<>c__DisplayClass6a.<EndCreateOrUpdateWorkflow>b__69() at Microsoft.Workflow.Gateway.WorkflowServiceGateway.ExceptionFilter[T](Func`1 body) at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)

May I registered workflow wrong host Uri
I also used non-System account to run the workflow.
Anybody can help me?

Comment: Yeah, I know the reasons why? It's just I didn't install Service bus update 01 correctly (must restart after installed).All of things to do is uninstall workflow manager and then reinstall it carefully! Following this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193489.aspx

Answer (score 1):

*This answer is community wiki. Feel free to improve.*

According to Topic Starter, the solution to this problem is the reinstallation of Workflow Manager and subsequent server restart.